# How to find records that don't have a value in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'FinTrans' that has data that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------
|AcctID     |TransCode |TransAmt|
---------------------------------
|1234567    |TOLL      |    4:30|
---------------------------------
|1234567    |PYMT      |    5:30|
---------------------------------
|1234567    |RFND      |    1:00|
---------------------------------
|2345678    |TOLL      |    4:30|
---------------------------------
|2345678    |TOLL      |    4:30|
---------------------------------
|2345678    |RFND      |    4:30|
---------------------------------
|3456789    |TOLL      |    4:30|
---------------------------------
```

And I have an 'Account' Table that gives the account number for each AcctID.

I need to  find Account Numbers that don't have 'PYMT' as the TransCode.

I have tried the following code but clearly that didn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.AccountNumber)      
      ,TransCode
      ,SUM(TransAmt)

  FROM FinTrans F
  INNER JOIN Account A ON F.AcctID = A.AccountID

  WHERE TransCode = 'TOLL'
    AND TransCode != 'PYMT'

  GROUP BY A.AccountNumber, TransCode
```

Comment: you have two tables in the query..but you only show one table. what's the expected result?

Comment: transcode is part of which table?

Comment: Table 1__As shown. Table2__AcctID, AccountNumber. TransCode is for Table 1 'FinTrans'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
FROM FinTrans F INNER JOIN
     Account A
     ON F.AcctID = A.AccountID
WHERE TransCode IN ('PYMT', 'TOLL')
GROUP BY A.AccountNumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TransCode = 'PYMT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Do you really need the other columns in your sample SQL?  They are not relevant to your question.

You can also do this with `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from account a
where exists (select 1
              from FinTrans f
              where f.AcctID = a.AccountID and f.TransCode = 'TOLL'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from FinTrans f
                  where f.AcctID = a.AccountID and f.TransCode = 'PYMT'
                 );
```

This has the performance advantage that no aggregation is necessary.

Comment: Got an error message with your earlier code: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

Answer (score 1):

I need to find Account Numbers that don't have 'PYMT' as the TransCode

You can try this... using group by having

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,TransCode
      ,SUM(TransAmt)

  FROM FinTrans F
  INNER JOIN Account A ON F.AcctID = A.AccountID
  where TransCode IN ('PYMT', 'TOLL')
  GROUP BY A.AccountNumber, TransCode
  HAVING SUM(IIF(TransCode = 'PYMT',1,0)) = 0
```

Comment: So, like my conditions specify, I want all AccountNumbers that have TOLL but do not have PYMT. What will be the code for that?

Comment: You definitely don't say that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the normal way to do `NOT HAVING`:

```
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM Account AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT NULL FROM FinTrans AS f
      WHERE a.AccountID = f.AcctID AND
            f.TransCode = "PYMT")
```

Trying to interpret your example instead, I believe you are looking for

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, f.TransCode, SUM(f.TransAmt)
FROM FinTrans AS f
INNER JOIN Account AS a ON f.AcctID = a.AccountID
WHERE f.AcctID IN (SELECT f.AcctID FROM FinTrans AS F GROUP BY f.AcctID 
                   HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN f.TransCode = 'PYMT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0)
      AND f.TransCode = 'TOLL'
GROUP BY f.AcctID
```

Another option using the first method of filtering the groups would be

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, f.TransCode, SUM(f.TransAmt)
FROM FinTrans AS f
INNER JOIN Account AS a ON f.AcctID = a.AccountID
WHERE f.AcctID IN (SELECT AcctID FROM FinTrans AS f 
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM FinTrans AS f2
                                     WHERE f.AcctID = f2.AcctID AND f2.TransCode = "PYMT"))
                         AND f.TransCode = 'TOLL'
GROUP BY f.AcctID;
```

Comment: So, like my conditions specify, I want all AccountNumbers that have TOLL but do not have PYMT. What will be the code for that?

Comment: I thought your conditions stated *I need to find Account Numbers that don't have 'PYMT' as the TransCode* and say nothing about TOLL? In any case, I think my updates are what you want.